# Filling dropdown field in PDF

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, itext7

I am trying to use the following code to fill the dropdown field.

```
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
form.GetField("country").SetValue("HKG");
form.FlattenFields();
```

Everything is working if I don't add FlattenFields(). It can show correct text which is "Hong Kong". However, if I add FlattenFields(), it will show "HKG".
I want to export a pdf without input control, so I add FlattenFields().
How to show "Hong Kong" after FlattenFields()?

Comment: Does it display HKG or Hong Kong. Your text is quite confusing.

Comment: It display HKG, but I expect it is Hong Kong

Comment: @KJ I just find the issue. It is because I added FlattenFields(). However, I need this function to export a pdf without input control. Any idea?